# Is there a classical textbook about elementary geometry covering it with the same rigor as Chrystal's Algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation, programming

I just have started to read [Elements of Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0578222140) by [Stepanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) and McJones, and in the preface they explained that the the book requires a basic algebra knowledge and they recommended [G. Chrystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Chrystal)'s [Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821819313) book as a nice refresher. Looking at the comments in Amazon and on some other places I realized that this is some very classical book about elementary algebra, famous for its rigor and difficulty despite that it covers algebra material typically taught in high school.

Then I started to wonder whether there exists such a classical book for the Euclidean geometry taught in high school. I mean a book which cover all or at least the most of high school's geometry, but with more rigor and details than typical modern classes. Maybe [Euclid's Elements](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/bookIII.html#defs) is an obvious answer, but I hope for something a bit more modern. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. David Hilbert. Foundations Of Geometry.
2. Donald Coxeter. Introduction To Geometry.

Comment: There is also Geometry Re-Visited, also by Coxeter, a short book on some topics not covered in Introduction To Geometry.